# return to state where apps get error android

Tags: android

i have made an app.which is working fine .now i am trying to ensure an issue that, by chance my app get error and stop unfortunately , then how to ensure that the app will run from the state it get stopped. i am trying to make sure the error state like if whatsApp , facebook, skype gets erro they starts exactly from the state they got exception. i am new in android development ,i searched in internet a lot on this topic unfortunately i am unable to find the exact soluton. please need some help on this .thank you

Comment: I don't know exactly which states you mean but there are several callback methods that are called when your `Activity` or `Fragment` is going to die and when reborn. for saving e.g. `onSaveInstanceState()` and for restoring: `onRestoreInstanceState()` and you can override them to save and load your state `:)`

Comment: oh thank you very much helpful :) .

Comment: **`Happy Coding!`** `:)`

Answer (score 1):

whatsapp, viber and other applications get all their data from the server so for them its as easy as just storing the activity or fragment name in the sharedPreferences and when app restarts again direct you to the stored activity or fragment and call the APIs again.

I have done something like you want in one of applications. though my app didtn use any API so I had all my datas in the DB and just had to save the present view  name (in shared preferences) user is in by now always. then if app closes or killed by any reason I cud load the same view next time.

Comment: my app is also server based app. and i am afraid of getting the error situation as i told above. so how to move forward?

Comment: yes it needs to be done manually. just save the name of every top view that user enters in in the shared preferences. then in your splash check whatever you save and direct the app to that point manually by code. its not an easy task. android doesnt do this for you automatically.

Comment: okay thank you.if i do not do that will the app run and behave well if user close and restart the app.

Comment: was that a question ? there is another way that you can start app just after crashing and say "sorry about crash" for example. that works by catching all unhandled exception in the whole app ;)

Comment: sorry for silly ques. as far i know it should work fine but i tried one app in a real device will behave weird after restarting on error. that is why asked . may be it was device problem .

Comment: no if you do that youll be ok in restarting and getting back. but every time you get back to the last view you were in.